# Converting individual characters of a string into ASCII values on one line, C

Tags: c

keep in mind i'm a complete beginner and i'm still getting acclimated to the programming vocabulary.

When I run the debug from visual studio, the command prompt comes up with "Enter any string: " but when I enter something, i get "Exception thrown blah blah blah". What is going wrong? Any help and criticism is greatly appreciated. I've been losing my mind over this for 4 hours now.

Heres my code:

```
int main(){

    char str[100];
    int i=0;

    printf("Enter any string: ");
    scanf_s("%s",str);

    printf("ASCII values of each characters of given string: ");
    while(str[i])
         printf("%d ",str[i++]);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's kinda funny how `scanf_s()` is supposed to be "safer". I keep seeing it misused  horribly.

Comment: `scanf_s("%s",str);` --> `scanf_s("%99s", str, sizeof str);`

Comment: "*Exception thrown blah blah blah. What's wrong?*" - That "blah blah blah" bit is where the information is. :S Somewhere in the past 4 hours you must have read that message. ;o)

Comment: I don't use Windows and consequently don't know exactly what `scanf_s` does, but if I replace it with `scanf`, then this program works for me, at least. And I see no obvious reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: That seems kind of belt-and-suspenders. Why both `scanf_s()` with a limit *and* `%99s`?

Comment: lol so i took BLUEPIXY's advice and now i'm getting a LNK1168 error... I'm going to post a different question with different code that might make more sense

Comment: @EOF if you use MSVC, try [this](http://ideone.com/S5A8oo) input `abcdefg`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Sorry, I'm on Linux. The only problem I see with your example is the undefined behavior for passing a `size_t` in place of `rsize_t` (or `unsigned` according to Microsoft).

Comment: @EOF The main thing is that both of the operation is not the same.

Comment: @EOF C defines `rsize_t` as `size_t` in its normative section K. Yet agree `(rsize_t) sizeof (...)` or equivalent is better.

Comment: @chux: Somebody should notify Microsoft that their interpretation of the bounds-checking interfaces is not C11-compliant. Oh, wait...

Comment: @EOF [Embrace, enhance, extinguish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend_and_extinguish)

Comment: @chux: Well, considering that a) Microsoft doesn't even do C99, and b) Nobody *but* Microsoft uses the bounds-checking interfaces, I'd say this is a bit ridiculous at this point.

Comment: 1) use standard C library functions.  I.E. use `scanf()` not `scanf_s()`  2) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful. 3) when using the '%s' input/conversion specifier, always use a 'max characters' modifier that is 1 less than the actual length of the input buffer.  I.E. `if( 1 != scanf( "%99s", str ) ) { // handle error }`   Without the 'max characters' modifier, the user can overrun the input buffer, which is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: The posted code contains a 'magic' number.  (100)  'magic' numbers are numbers without a basis.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give magic numbers meaningful names, Then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scanf_s()` function must be used with a third argument to indicate the max length of the string i.e. `scanf_s("%s", str, 100);`

BTW `scanf_s()` is specific to Microsoft Visual Studio so it's less portable so I don't recommend it and `str` isn't a really good variable name

Comment: `scanf_s()` is in Microsoft Visual Studio and it is in C11's _Annex K (normative) Bounds-checking interfaces_.

Comment: The 100 should be of type `rsize_t` per C, and `unsigned` per MS.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The posted code is:

1. not portable
2. contains 'magic' (not basis for value) numbers
3. spreads the variable `i` declaration far from its' usage
4. will not input past a 'white space' character

The following code corrects those problems, checks for errors, and compiles cleanly

```
#include <stdio.h>   // scanf(), printf(), perror()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

#define MAX_STR_LEN (100)

int main( void )
{

    char str[ MAX_STR_LEN ];

    printf("Enter any string: ");
    if( NULL == fgets( str, sizeof(str), stdin ))
    {
        perror( "fgets failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    printf("ASCII values of each characters of given string: ");
    for( size_t i=0; str[i]; i++ )
         printf("%d ",str[i]);


    return 0;
}
```

Note: the above code will input the newline and print it (10 on linux)  You might want to use something to eliminate the newline, so insert the following, right after the call to `fgets()`:

```
char *newline = NULL;
if( NULL != ( newline = strstr( str, "\n" ) ) )
{ // carriage return found
    *newline = '\0';
}
```

This method of eliminating the newline char means the code also needs:

```
#include <string.h> // strstr()
```